# declaring double arrays in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

My map object has a set of coordinates. It doesn't always have the same number of coordinates.
In java I'd just declare the object as `Double[] xpoints` and would set it's size when instantiating a map like this: `xpoints = new double[npoints]`;

How can I do this with objective-c?

I tried doing this: `@property(nonatomic) double * xpoints;` but somehow all of it's values turn to 0 when I print it with NSLog.

Map's init:

```
-(id)initWithXpoints:(double[]) xpointss Ypoints:(double[]) ypointss Npoints:(int)npointss
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.xpoints = xpointss;
        self.ypoints = ypointss;
        self.npoints = npointss;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Something weird happens though. The values are changed to zero when I print xpoints[0] from the object that created the map. The first time I print it it works. The second time it just prints zero.

I think it happens because xpointss sent to init is removed from the memory. How can I "instantiate" the xpoints property if it's a pointer?

Is there a better way to do this?

added: I tried creating a temporary xpoints like this:

```
double tempxpoints[npointss];
double tempypoints[npointss];
for (int i = 0; i < npointss; i++)
{
    tempxpoints[i] = xpointss[i];
    tempypoints[i] = ypointss[i];
}
self.xpoints = tempxpoints;
self.ypoints = tempypoints;
```

But it still didn't work.

Edit: Thanks for all the answers. This ended up being my final Init code:

```
-(id)initWithXpoints:(double[]) xpointss Ypoints:(double[]) ypointss Npoints:(int)npointss
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
         _xpoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
         _ypoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
         for (int i = 0; i < npointss; i++)
         {
             NSNumber *tempx = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:xpointss[i]];
             NSNumber *tempy = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:ypointss[i]];
             [_xpoints addObject:tempx];
             [_ypoints addObject:tempy];
         }
         _npoints = npointss;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using `NSArray` instead?

Comment: I guess I can do that. But since I'm porting an app that was made for Android (by someone else) I'm avoiding changing it too much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you allocate the arrays as local variables, then they will be allocated on the stack. When execution leaves the function, those memory areas are freed up. You must use `malloc()` to allocate arrays that you can pass around and use `free()` to free them up.

```
// to allocate
double[] tempxpoints = (double[])malloc(sizeof(double) * npointss);

// to free when not used any more
free(tempxpoints);
```

But actually `NSArray` has been designed to handle these cases. And with ARC you don't even have to care about freeing the memory.

```
NSMutableArray *tempxpoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[tempxpoints addObject:@2]; // wrap the double in an NSNumber object
```

Comment: NSArray can't hold upwrapped doubles, though.

Comment: You probably mean `NSMutableArray` in your last line. - And it depends on the application. For some task boxing and unboxing the numbers might add a considerable overhead.

Comment: The array won't be changed/added to. Is there a quick way to initialize an NSarray with a double[]?

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't. You have to add the objects one by one. But once you have the arrays, there are methods to compose them.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I edited my question with the working init code. If there's anything I should be doing differently please tell me.

Comment: I'd rather use the @ notation for boxing as that is more compact but otherwise looks good.

Answer (score 3):

If you were being fully Objective-C about it, you'd use an `NSArray`, fill it with `NSNumber`s and never specify a length. You can usually give them hints about how much space is likely to be required but Objective-C's collections all always size dynamically.

As of recent versions of the compiler, you can use `array[x]` notation on `NSArray` and write direct `NSNumber` constants as e.g. `@4.5f` if that sweetens the deal at all.

If you literally want C-style arrays then you'll need to descend to the C level of thought. So, something like:

`@property(nonatomic, readonly) double * xpoints;`

And:

```
-(id)initWithXpoints:(double[]) xpointss Ypoints:(double[]) ypointss Npoints:(int)npointss
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        size_t sizeOfArraysInBytes = sizeof(double)*npointss;
        _xpoints = (double *)malloc(sizeOfArraysInBytes);
        memcpy(_xpoints, xpointss, sizeOfArraysInBytes);
        /* ... etc ... */

        /* you never use self. notation in an init because it's a method call,
        and method calls on objects that are not yet fully instantiated aren't
        safe. Sample cause of failure: a subclass overrides the setter */
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    free(_xpoints);
    /* ... etc ... */
}
```

The array itself will be read/write elsewhere (it's the pointer that's read-only, not the things it points to) as `class.xpoints[0]`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I decided to go with NSMutableArray so I don't have to worry about deallocating it.